# Where to ask/answer 10 questions?

Tags: support, area-51

I'm a bit confused, because I registered as a "Committer" for the "Physics" Area 51 proposal. The FAQ says

"Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site."

I've no idea how to answer or ask questions for it. There is no button anywhere (I wanted to add an "on-topic" question).

Also, there already seems to be a https://physics.stackexchange.com/, but it seems to be unrelated to this proposal, because it doesn't have that typical Stack Exchange look like, for example, the Tex/LaTeX site has, and I heard someone saying that that site is an old, nearly-dead try to establish such a community.

So, where can I "fulfill" my commitment to the new community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different phases of an SE 2 proposal; they're somewhat listed in the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

The on/off-topic questions are added during the **definition** phase. If you look on the [list of proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?page=2&tab=progress) and select one in the definition phase (it will have an orange "followers" box and the progress bar will be in the "define" section):

[image: Screenshot of the Coffee proposal in definition phase]

you will see an area at the bottom of the question list to propose your own questions:

[image: Screenshot of the question proposal section]

---

The [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics) proposal already has enough questions, so it's moved to the next phase, **commitment**. It has a green-ish "committed" box:

[image: Screenshot of the Physics proposal in commitment phase]

If you go to the actual proposal you can also see the current phase on the right-hand side. Commitment happens after definition is done; there are enough questions to define the scope of the site, and now they're just recruiting people to participate in the beta. Once they have enough, the beta will begin. You fulfill your commitment by participating during the beta; you need to post 10 times (questions or answers) to fulfill a commitment

Comment: Ah i see now. This explains all i wanted to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait 'till the site enters private beta. You will be notified when this occurs.

The site you are referring to is a SE 1.0 site.

Comment: Hmm, will it not conflict with the new site? I wonder how they are gonna solving this. And I wonder who created all those example on-topic and off-topic questions.

Comment: @litb: you can click on the questions. also, you can look at the entire [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?phase=definition) by clicking on the definition tab to view all questions proposed (but no longer vote, but this is just a draft anyway, the direction may still change a bit depending on the community). http://physics.stackexchange.com and http://physicsoverflow.com are SE-1.0 sites which are likely to be close, see [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/), but may be merged into the SE-2.0 site